# Is there a connection string property to specify size of binary or text data ADO.NET for SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string

The connection string for .NET Framework Sybase ADO Provider has a property for the maximum size of binary or text data in bytes that will be sent to or received from ASE. TextSize=64000 sets this limit to 64K bytes. Default is 32K.

Below is the connection string a .net application that loads PDFs to the DB is using for Sybase 15:

```
"DataSource='myserver';Port='1200';UID='myuserid';PWD='********';Database='mydbname';TextSize='2000000000';"
```

It's set with that big number supposedly to avoid file getting truncated when retrieved from DB.

I'm poring this application from .NET Framework 2.0 against Sybase to .NET Framework 4 against SQL Server 2008, and I did not find an equivalent property for SQL Server ADO.NET dataprovider.

I'm thinking it may no longer be necessary for SQL 2008 and that's why it does not exist.

Will appreciate some help if anyone can confirm this thought/finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find an equivalent connection string property to specify size of binary or text data using ADO.NET for SQL Server 2008.

However, I have not had any data truncation issues when retrieving/storing big PDF files.

Below is a link to a table that lists the valid names for keyword values within the ConnectionString when using .NET Framework System.Data.SqlClient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to utilize the FileStream storage option available in 2008.  Using FileStream storage for binary data removes significant headaches when trying to store that type of data in tables.  Using FileStream does not require any specific options wrt connection strings, so you don't need to worry about creating buffers for binary data.

FileStream storage is transactionaly consistent with the database and is easily available for use within .NET.

IIRC, there is an excellent tutorial/demo in Books Online for using FileStream storage from both the Win32 API and T-SQL.  I used it several years ago as a prototype for testing the then-new FS option.